# AJAX Form in a jQuery Popup - Need a way to clear content on popup close

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a dynamic listing of products which is being pulled from a MySQL Database.  On each one there is an option to "Contact Now" which leads to a [jQuery Popup](http://yensdesign.com/2008/09/how-to-create-a-stunning-and-smooth-popup-using-jquery/).

Now the form is being submitted via AJAX, here is the [code](http://pastebin.com/6X18jyn0) for it.  So when I click the "Send" button with no information, the error div shows up that says I need to fill out all fields.

If I close this popup and then go to another page and open up another brand, I get the same error message.  So when I fill in the form successfully and get a Success Message, and close the popup and open up a new brand the Success message shows, and I am unable to fill anything out until I refresh the page.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: If this problem (as you described) happens on the same page not on different pages (reloaded pages) then you need to re-initiate the popup object. If it happens on different pages that means the plugin is using cookies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the event that triggers the close, clear the element containing the message.  An example using jQuery is:

```
$("#closeButton").click(function() {
    $("#errorMessage").hide(); 
});
```